# Best practice for single client servers?

Tags: java, networking, io

Is it better to kick off one thread that will handle one client and another for each other one that connects but tells them the server is busy, or should I just stick with a singlethreaded approach where the same thread accepts and processes the client so others can't connect to it? (if that's the case of course)

Edit: I should note that there won't be 239482340 people connecting to it. Generally only one person will be connecting to the server, but I want my app to deal with another person trying to connect without falling over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to a single thread is better for the server since the resource consumption is very low. However, this is probably annoying for the client since it doesn't know if there is something wrong with the server or if it is just busy.

Having threads that tell additional users that the server is busy takes up more resources but is better for the client.

In your particular case, either approach should be fine. I guess it really depends on the clients and what they want... :-/

Comment: User experience is important here, so maybe it's better I put the effort in. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Two major strategies are commonly used to build this kind of systems:

- A solution based on a multithread strategy, assigning a different thread or process to the each incoming request. This model is used in many commercial servers
- The event-driven model, is based on the use of non-blocking I/O operations to respond simultaneously to a number of requests coming from different clients. This is a growing approach.